# How to use case when function

Tags: sql

How can I exclude this code when I use case when function as below;
Can I use 'from' in case when function?

```
          SPRIDEN_ID NOT IN ((SIBINST_TERM=
             (select max(SIBINST_TERM)
                       from sibinst
                       where SIBINST_TERM<'201920'
                              and sibinst_id=spriden_id)
                 and SIBINST_FCS='AC' 
             ))
```

I want to put this in this code as below but this gives error on 
from says missiong right paranthesis

```
select  distinct 
       spriden_last,        
        case WHEN  (SPRIDEN_ID IN (SELECT SGBSTDN_ID FROM SGBSTDN) AND 
                    SPRIDEN_ID NOT IN ((SIBINST_TERM=
             (select max(SIBINST_TERM)
                       from sibinst
                       where SIBINST_TERM<'201920'
                              and sibinst_id=spriden_id)
                 and SIBINST_FCS='AC' 
             )))
                    THEN 'S'      END AS FF        
   FROM SPRIDEN,SIBINST
   WHERE spriden_id=sibinst_id     ;
```

Comment: Remove comma after FF.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.